# Executar função apos determinado tempo que tiver parado de digitar (keyup) VueJS ou JS Puro

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou tentando fazer que ao parar de digitar no input, o sistema espere um segundo para fazer minha busca e retornar meu resultado, mas não estou conseguindo. O sistema esta sendo feito em VueJS

```
        <input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa1" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(valorPesquisa1, 1)" placeholder="Informe nome">
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa2" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(valorPesquisa2, 2)" placeholder="Informe nome, CNPJ, CPF ou CUT">
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa2" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(valorPesquisa3, 2)" placeholder="Informe nome, CNPJ, CPF ou CUT">
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa2" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(valorPesquisa4, 2)" placeholder="Informe nome, CNPJ, CPF ou CUT">

    searchApi6(val,box){
                    let typingTimer;
                    let doneTypingInterval = 1000;

                    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
                    if(val.length > 2){


                        typingTimer = setTimeout(function(){
                            switch(box){
                              case 1:
                                this.textArea1 = true
                                break;
                              case 2:
                                this.textArea2 = true
                                break;
                              case 3:
                                this.textArea3 = true
                                break;
                              case 4:
                                this.textArea4 = true
                                break;
                            }
                            axios.get(url+'ListaPessoa?Token='+localStorage['id']+'&Filtro='+val)
                            .then(response => {

                              switch(box){
                              case 1:
                                this.autocomplete1 = false;
                                break;
                              case 2:
                                this.autocomplete2 = false;
                                break;
                              case 3:
                                this.autocomplete3 = false;
                                break;
                              case 4:
                                this.autocomplete4 = false;
                                break;
                            }
                              this.searchPeople = response.data;
                            })
                            .catch(error => {
                              console.log(error);
                            })
                        }, doneTypingInterval);

                    }
                }

data(){
            return{
                data: this.$route.params.data,
                doctoBLID: this.$route.params.doctoBLID,
                valorPesquisa1: '',
                textArea1: true,
                textArea2: true,
                textArea3: true,
                textArea4: true,
                textPeople1: '',
                textPeople2: '',
                textPeople3: '',
                textPeople4: '',
                autocomplete1: true,
                autocomplete2: true,
                autocomplete3: true,
                autocomplete4: true,
                searchPeople: [],
                bloco2: true,
                bloco3: true,
                bloco4: true,
                textId1: '',
                textId2: '',
                textId3: '',
                textId4: '',
                valorPesquisa2: '',
                valorPesquisa3: '',
                valorPesquisa4: ''
            }
        }
```

Porem não estou conseguindo

Comment: Podes colocar o objeto do componente onde tens o `valorPesquisa1`?

Comment: valorPesquisa1 esta definido no data do vue como branco, ai ele esta no v-model do input

Comment: Sim, isso eu imaginei, mas eu queria ver o JS que tens nesse componente para poder responder à pergunta com o teu código corrigido.

Comment: O unico lugar que eu uso ele é aqui 

<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa1" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(valorPesquisa1, 1)" placeholder="Informe nome">

Comment: Rafael, tens alguns erros no código. Se quiseres colocar o teu código posso ajudar e dar uma resposta. Sem ver o teu código vou estar a adivinhar e a resposta é menos util para ti. Devias ter esse `valorPesquisa1` no `data` também...

Comment: @Sergio eu editei o codigo, e adicionei todo o data

Comment: Ótimo. Tens mais inputs onde fazes pesquisa nesse componente? vejo `valorPesquisa2` até 4

Comment: @Sergio coloquei lá os outros inputs, são 4 inputs que fazem busca, eles usam a mesma função, pois buscam na mesma API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifiquei o teu código para não declarar variáveis repetitivamente.

Deves ter em conta que esse método `searchApi6` deve estar dentro do objeto para os métodos: `methods`.

Um exemplo do teu código corrigido (e simplificando com o que não faz parte) seria:

```js
{

  data() {
      return {
        data: this.$route.params.data,
        doctoBLID: this.$route.params.doctoBLID,
        valorPesquisa: {},
        typeTimeout: null,
        doneTypingInterval: 1000,
        autocomplete: {},
        textArea: {}
        // etc...
      }
    },
    methods: searchApi6(box) {

      clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);

      const val = this.valorPesquisa[box] || '';
      if (val.length > 2) {
        this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
          this.textArea[box] = true
          axios.get(url + 'ListaPessoa?Token=' + localStorage.id + '&Filtro=' + val)
            .then(response => {
              this.autocomplete[box] = false;
              this.searchPeople = response.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
            })
        }, this.doneTypingInterval);
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa1" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(1)" placeholder="Informe nome">
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa2" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(2)" placeholder="Informe nome, CNPJ, CPF ou CUT">
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa2" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(3)" placeholder="Informe nome, CNPJ, CPF ou CUT">
<input class="input" type="text" v-model="valorPesquisa2" v-on:keyup="searchApi6(4)" placeholder="Informe nome, CNPJ, CPF ou CUT">
```

Nota: Não uses a chave de nome `data` aqui: `data: this.$route.params.data,` usa outro nome para não misturar com a chave `data` do Vue que é reservada.

Comment: No caso, o val que você está pegando, está vindo de onde? pois você tirou o val da função, só fiquei confuso ai, mas seu codigo com toda certeza, ficou muito mais limpo :D

Comment: @RafaelAugusto estou de viagem hoje e dai o silencio, lamento. Pois a ideia era evitar repetição. Se tiveres no data `valorPesquisa: {},` como objeto e depois passares somente `v-on:keyup="searchApi6(1)"` aí podes tirar o val do input que receber o keyup com `const val = this.valorPesquisa[box] || '';` e assim o mesmo código funciona para 1 ou mil inputs sem ter de repetir código.

Answer (score 0):

Refiz a resposta com js puro.

```js
var tempo = null;

document.getElementById('nome').addEventListener("keyup", teste);

function teste(){
var v = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  clearTimeout(tempo);
  tempo = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Buscar : " + v); }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Nome : <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="">
```

Comment: Não estou usando jQuery, e nem pretendo, em jQuery eu sei fazer, só pode ser em JS Puro/VueJS.

Comment: Alterei para js puro.